# boost::program_options: Is it possible to set one option as default value for another?

Tags: c++, default-value, boost-program-options

I'm currently trying to implement the boost::program_options library in my simulation. While reading in (many) parameters I would like to do something like this

```
namespace po = boost::program_options;
po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("option1", po::value<int>(&int1), "set value for option1")
    ("option2", po::value<int>(&int2)->default_value(int1), "set value for option2, default is option1")
;
```

Problem: default_value(int1) does not use the provided int1, if both options are given simultaneously (either per command line or config file) and instead used the value before notify().

I know that the problem can be solved with simply checking if option2 was provided and assigning the default value later. The problem is, that I would like to avoid writing this IF statement for ~30 parameters with a cleaner solution.

If needed, this is the rest of the program_option code

```
po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);

if (vm.count("config")) {
    std::ifstream cfs(config_file, std::ifstream::in);
    po::store(po::parse_config_file(cfs, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
}
```

where the "config" option has the config_file path as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only want to call notify once, at the end.

I tried to make a notifier to do this, but you can't change a value in the variables_map after the fact.  Best I could come up with is to create a fake variable, but then storing it to the variables_map became too much work and I gave up!